# XAMPP-Project not working on different computers

Tags: php, url

So, I Have REST URL to register like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/task_manager/v1/register
```

And then, I try the URL in Google Chrome Advanced Rest Client.
Everything goes smoothly.

**And now I decided to test the URL on another computer.
So I copy paste the file to another computer and test the URL once again.**

But the result is I got 404 ERROR, Object not found.

Did I hit something wrong ?
I copy all the file correctly.
This is weird.

***UPDATE : I use all the folder which contains all the files and I using same version of XAMPP & PHP on that both computers***

Comment: You copied which files? How was PHP configured on the other computer? And the web server? How did you change the url? This question lacks too much information.

Comment: I copied all the folder which contains the project. the localhost port is correctly same.

Comment: I do not know why the URL can not working when I try on another computer. I using Google Chrome Advanced Rest Client too on that computer.

Comment: webserver configuration? document root setting?

Comment: because you have a running webserver on your local. Are you sure is there a webserver on test machine ?

Comment: what gives just http://localhost on the other machine?

Comment: @GolezTrol : I do the same configuration and document root setting

Comment: @erkandemir : I am using XAMPP for both computers

Comment: I am using same port for both computer: It's localhost:8080

Comment: Can you access project when you write localhost on browser. check your port 8000. it can be diffenrent.

Comment: @erkandemir : yes I can access the index.html from the folder. But when I try to use the action page which is contain the URL, It said error 404

Comment: do you have an .htaccess file? Maybe there is a routing and you missed copying it because it's hidden file?

Comment: @abimelex : yes I have, But my folder is already containing it

Comment: how did you tested that xampp and your project is running?

Comment: @abimelex : I have index.html page, I tested that page and everything going well, but when I tested the URL, it can not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localhost targets on your computer, means the actual machine the files are on. If you are using php > 5.3 you can use php's build in development server with

```
php -S __YOUR LOCAL IP__ : 8000
```

and access the site from all the computers within your network

For example, if you run

```
php -S 192.168.0.1:8000
```

on your development machine, you can access it via

```
http://192.168.0.1:8000/
```

from every device connected to your local network

As you have written in your comment you have copied all the files, it is most likely that you either don't have php, apache or a webserver (MAMP,WAMP,...) installed (or started) on the other machine, or you just didn't copy the files to the correct folder.

Comment: I already copy all the folder contains the files. I using same PHP version too on that both computer.

Comment: I already copying all the folders to the correct folder and I use XAMPP for both

Answer (score 1):

an url beginning with `localhost` refers to the computer where it's called from. See wikipedia [localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

To provide the same behavior on another computer you need to copy the whole project and install the used server software e.g. apache, mysql etc. pp. or access the project from another computer in the same network using the internal network IP instead of localhost.

FYI: localhost is almost the same like the loop-IP `127.0.0.127`

so on the computer where it works there should also work: `http://127.0.0.127:8080/task_manager/v1/register`
Now replace the `127.0.0.127` with the IP of your computer when testing it on another computer

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your project on a webserver like your local.